# How to bind ESC to keyboard-escape-quit in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Normally [keyboard-escape-quit](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Quitting.html) is bound to <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>. Is it possible to rebind it to a single <kbd>Esc</kbd>? I never use Escape as a prefix key.

I'm running Emacs 23.0.60.1 on Windows XP.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Rehashing other's answer, I have

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<escape>")      'keyboard-escape-quit)
```

in my .emacs file, and it works on my emacs 22 on WinXP. I also hate typing 3 ESC in a row; and from years of (windows) habits my finger goes so naturally to the escape key for getting out of anything unpleasant.

Answer (score 4):

Not to say this is right for you, but when I had this problem I taught myself to press Ctrl-g instead, which is also bound to keyboard-escape-quit by default.  For me, this has the advantage of keeping my left hand pretty close to the home position, as well as leaving my Esc prefix intact.

Edit: After reading through the linked page, it's not bound to exactly the same function, and on Windows Ctrl-g can't forcibly interrupt a running command, but Ctrl-g covers 99% of what I would use Esc Esc Esc for --- aborting a command that I screwed up entering.

Comment: I never use `keyboard-escape-quit`, I use C-g.  Can't say I reach for C-[, which would be the other part of the functionality to mimic ESC ESC ESC.

Comment: I'll try to use C-g to not to leave the home position but Esc is already burned into my brain as "get me back to where I was" so I need it. Otherwise I press Esc -> nothing happens -> I feel unhappy.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but at the expense of killing the Esc prefix key map
The code to do this is 
(global-set-key "" 'keyboard-escape-quit)
where the funny char is is escape (use ^Q esc to type it in)
it will map esc for you but the rest of the keymap is gone
after that

Comment: You can avoid typing the funny character by doing (global-set-key (kbd "ESC") 'keyboard-escape-quit), but it is not as simple as that: at least on my Emacs (22.3.1 on a Mac, Carbon version 1.6.0) ESC doesn't work as the quit key, but all meta keystrokes (even using Cmd) stop working.

Comment: ya, that's the behavior on Win32 Emacs 22.0.99