# How to bind ESC to Quit (C-g) in emacs for Mac

Tags: macos, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using emacs 24.0.95 for Mac (from emacsformacosx.com builds).

I've tried doing

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<escape>") 'keyboard-escape-quit)
```

as suggested in a similar (but win specific) question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648817/how-to-bind-esc-to-keyboard-escape-quit-in-emacs) which seems to work in Win but not on Mac, all meta keystrokes stop working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot help with your OSX issue specifically as I am on a linux machine here, but I do notice that C-g runs the command **keyboard-quit** and not **keyboard-escape-quit**. For the emacs docs you can invoke: **C-h k C-g** to see it... but here is what it says anyway:

"C-g runs the command keyboard-quit, which is an interactive compiled
Lisp function in `simple.el'.

It is bound to C-g.

(keyboard-quit)

Signal a `quit' condition.
During execution of Lisp code, this character causes a quit directly.
At top-level, as an editor command, this simply beeps."

So perhaps that might be of some help to you?

EDIT: and I can confirm that on my setup:

`(global-set-key (kbd "<escape>") 'keyboard-quit)`

succesfully rebinds **C-g** to a single Escape stroke.

Comment: I completely forgot about this question! I tested it in osx and it seems to do the trick, also it's a great answer, so I'm accepting this for future reference. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like it actually is bound to keyboard-escape-quit, irrelevant of what the doc says.
Binding to keyboard-quit behaves differently from C-g.